# DRF update resource with serializer with source argument

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following code.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   fax = serializers.CharField(source='primary_address.fax')

class User(models.Model):
    primary_address = models.OneToOneField(ProfileAddress, verbose_name=_('Primary address'), null=True, related_name='+')

class ProfileAddress(models.Model):
   fax = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Fax number'), null=True)
   mobile = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Mobile phone number'), null=True)
```

When i'm trying to update the User object by sending fax field i will get a error

```
Cannot assign "{u'fax': u'0555400123457'}": "User.primary_address" must be a "ProfileAddress" instance.
```

What is the proper way to update such fields, that define source argument that corresponds to the related models. There can be defined more fields on that related model, and they all should be represented in json output as field, not a nested field.

UPDATE
In my validated_data.items in serializer update i see following:

```
 (u'primary_address', {u'city': {u'name': u'Berlin'}, u'fax': u'0555400123457', u'url': None, u'line1': u'Sch\xf6nhauser Allee', u'phone': u'0555400123456', u'postal_code': u'PostalCode object', u'email': u'abv@gmsail.comso'}),  (u'title', u'Herr')
```

And obviously the update code from ModelSerializer:

```
for attr, value in validated_data.items():
    setattr(instance, attr, value)
```

Will just try to set primary_address attribute with dictionary value, and it will fail.

Comment: post your Profile and ProfileAddress model.

Comment: Profile is a User model, i modified. ProfileAddress added

Comment: Are you trying a PUT or PATCH? Maybe `update` does not work because you don't provide a full `ProfileAddress`. Try `partial_update`

Comment: im using patch method

Comment: The `validated_data` you posted does not match with the serializer. Looks like you are using a seperate `ProfileAddressSerializer` to me. Please post the full model / serializer.

Comment: No , i dont use separate serializer. I just stripped more fields from definition, that just defined same way , there just not 1 field, but 7+

Comment: @ilse2005 in validated data they are appearing as primary_address dict object with key inside it, and drf just tries to set this dictionary to primary_address field and fails

Answer (score 2):

you should override the `update` function to update the `primary_address.fax` by yourself.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fax = serializers.CharField(source='primary_address.fax')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        fax = validated_data.pop('fax', None)
        super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
        if fax is not None:
            instance.primary_address.fax = fax
            instance.primary_address.save(update_fields=('fax',))
        return instance
```

Comment: Thats not a god way. If i have 10+ such fields i will need to to a lot of manual update. Doesnt sound like a good solution.,

Comment: Also it simple doesnt work. There wont be such field as fax in validated data. What actually appears in validated data is following: (u'primary_address', {u'city': {u'name': u'Berlin'}, u'fax': u'0555400123457', u'url': None, u'line1': u'Sch\xf6nhauser Allee', u'phone': u'0555400123456', u'postal_code': u'PostalCode object', u'email': u'abv@gmsail.comso'}), (u'email', u'abv@gmsail.comso.nil')

Comment: @Aldarund your validated data looks like not belongs to the `UserSerializer` you posted on the question.. can you post how you initiate the serializer instance?

Comment: it really belongs to it.. Im using ModelVIewSet with defined UserSerializer, thats all.  There just more field in serializer than i posted, but they all defined same way. No nested serializers.

Comment: In validated data there will be source names, not serializer names since in update fuction it just iterate through attr in validated_data and set it directly to model